# Why are my error styles being applied to the element when there's no error?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using angularjs (because of a legacy project), and I'm loading some images to fill a catalog.

In case of the image not existing I use onerror to set another image (a local one), and what I'm trying to do is to change the opacity of it too.

I have the next code:

```
<img src="https://myurl.com/image.png" 
     onerror="this.onerror=null; this.src='localImages/fallbackImg.png'; this.style.opacity=1"
style="opacity:0.5; position:absolute; width:100%; height:100%">
```

But this way all the images have `opacity: 1` instead of some having `opacity:0.5`and some `opacity: 1`.

Note: Also, that code snippet is generated inside a ng-repeat so i'm doing this set the images dynamically.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You should be doing all your styles with CSS classes. Anyway, are you saying that the onerror styles are being applied when there's no error? How can you tell?

Comment: code runs fine, not sure what your problem is. If they all have opacity 1, than there appears to be something else going on....

Comment: I know but I don't know how to pass an id (received from database and used on html with {{something.id}} ) to the css file because images are obtained from url using that id.

And yes even when no error or that's what I'm thinking because when there is an image it displays the remote one and when not it displays de local correctly.